# Does iOS 9 content blocker works in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari-content-blocker

Content blockers are enabled from Safari and work as extensions, but do they affect the UIWebView (in-app browser)?

Answer (score 2):

Information on that subject is still sparse, however it seems like the answer is no for UIWebView and WKWebView. On the other hand, SFSafariViewController is said to support content blocking.

See: https://www.macstories.net/stories/ios-9-and-safari-view-controller-the-future-of-web-views/

Comment: Does UIWebView, WKWebView and SFSafariViewController have same User-Agent string ? Or other way to understand where JS code is running ?